# How can i validate multiple editText fields and enable button?

Tags: android, validation, kotlin, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am trying to figure out how to validate 6 EditText input fields and enable button 
`button_step_one_next_FSF.isEnabled = true`
 when everything fits my condition. **I want to validate everything using this util class without creating TextWatcher object.**

Here is my editText util class

```
inline fun EditText.onTextChange(crossinline f: (s: CharSequence?) -> Unit) {
val listener = object : TextWatcher {
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                               before: Int, count: Int) {
        f(s)
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
}
addTextChangedListener(listener)
```

}

Here is short validation method  example

```
 private fun validateInput() {

    edit_text_name.onTextChange { s ->
        val name: String = s?.toString() ?: ""
        if (!name.isNameNotValid()) {
            text_input_name.isEndIconVisible = true
            text_input_name.isErrorEnabled = false
        } else {
            text_input_name.error = getString(R.string.error_not_valid_name)
            text_input_name.isEndIconVisible = false
        }
    }
    edit_text_surname.onTextChange { s ->
        val surname: String = s?.toString() ?: ""
        if (!surname.isNameNotValid()) {

            text_input_surname.isEndIconVisible = true
            text_input_surname.isErrorEnabled = false

        } else {
            text_input_surname.error = getString(R.string.error_not_valid_surname)
            text_input_surname.isEndIconVisible = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added this method checkButtonEnableState() at the end of each validation in TextWatcher lambda expression and it solved my problem!

```
private fun checkButtonEnableState() {
    button_step_one_next_FSF.isEnabled =
        (!edit_text_name.text.toString().isNameNotValid()
                && !edit_text_surname.text.toString().isNameNotValid()
                && edit_text_password_FSF.text.toString().isValidPassword()
                && edit_text_password_confirm_FSF.text.toString().isValidPassword()) &&
                (edit_text_password_confirm_FSF.text.toString() == edit_text_password_FSF.text.toString())
}
```